# Dirichlet series of convolution of conditionally convergent Dirichlet series is not necessarily convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In Montgomery and Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory, they claim the statement in this question's title, using the example $$ \alpha(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}n^{-s} $$ as the conditionally convergent series, for $0< \sigma < 1$, and state that the Dirichlet series of $\alpha(s)^2$ has abscissa of convergence $1/4$. However, I cannot see why the abscissa of convergence is $1/4$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{s=1}^\infty{\alpha^2(s)}$?

Comment: No, I mean the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n)n^{-s},$$ where $$c(n)=\sum_{d|n} (-1)^{d+n/d}$$ is the Dirichlet convolution of $(-1)^{n-1}$ with itself.